# Are Spellcasting Focuses inherently magical?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, spellcasting-focus

Im having a bit of a quarrel with my DM about if spellcasting focuses are magical. He believes that they are magical since it seems magical to him that you now dont need actual material components since your holding one, but I counter with  that no where does it state they are magical and that they are just a conduit for your magical power to come out.

I have looked around on the internet a bit but have found nothing about it, does anyone know a definitive answer to this?

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a great question—so good, in fact, that others have been wondering the same thing, and we already have a place for that question. If that answers your question, great! It’s useful to have this as another way for new users to find the information. If it *doesn’t* answer your question, feel free to edit this to explain what you still need, and we can open it back up for more answers.